# DIsplay employee working status per day of week

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
    users.name AS USER, 
    TIMESHEET.timesheet_date AS DAY, 
    TIMESHEET.STATUS AS STATUS
FROM TIMESHEET
JOIN users ON TIMESHEET.`rep_id` = users.`id`
WHERE WEEK(TIMESHEET.timesheet_date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) - 1
```

that returns the following: per employee, the working status for each date of LAST WEEK:

(sample)

```
USER                DAY         STATUS
Lee Fenelon         2012-07-02  Working
Tom Price           2012-07-02  Working
Kevin Duffy         2012-07-02  Working
Keith Donnelly      2012-07-02  Working
Graham Foley        2012-07-02  Sick Leave - No Medical Cert
Dominic Mallinson   2012-07-04  1/2 Day Sick Leave - No Medical Cert
```

What I'd like to do is modify the above so that I get 5 status per employee per week, ie `STATUS_MONDAY = Working`, `STATUS_TUESDAY=Sick leave` etc etc

The overall required output will be a report showing, for each employee, one columne per day with their working staus for that day.

Comment: careful: WEEK(datetime) gives the week within the year. So if you have last year's dates and this year's dates in TIMESHEET you'll get both.

Answer (score 0):

May be Pivot Table Works for You. you can refer this [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table) if it works